# Prevent multiple login in SPA application (react, nodeJS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, session, cookies

I am working on project using NodeJS and react native, and I am trying to prevent user from login from different browsers in the same time to fit with my needs, so I searched on the internet for the best solution but I didn't found any strong solution.
But I thought about saving user generated token with JWT in the database and each time the user login, I override the older token and save the new one then send it to front end to save it in cookies, but this make a problem, if the user copy the cookie and save it in the other browser, so he can connect multiple times.
What I ask for is if there is any good solution to resolve that problem or if there is other technology already used, I can get benefit of it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Reading [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/05/30/openid-oauth-saml/) link will help you to understand more about the principles of some authorizing protocols.

You have to add a expire_date for the authentication_key so it will update every 5 minutes for example and if someone steals the authentication key he can access just for 5 minutes

also you should have a refresh_token to refresh the authentication_token with it every 5 minutes for example .

Comment: and each time i refresh the token, i have to save it in the database ?

Comment: yes, you can delete the other ones that used before. also if you use JWT you can stop using database and handle this problem without database.

Comment: i use it, could you explain more details please ?

Comment: this article will help you more : https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/

Comment: So what you suggest is to save the JWT in  **httpOnly cookie** instead of save it in the database ? if yes i would know, if i add the userAgent information to the JWT and compare it each time with the request user agent would be a good idea or no ?

Comment: if httpOnly cookie, is copied and pasted manually from browser to an other, would server accept it ?

Comment: @frouja you can't access httpOnly cookie and so you can't change it.

Comment: @frouja you have several ways to compare and you can do what you have said

Comment: if u could propose others ? because even if i use what i ve said i and i don't save the token in database i have nothing to compare with when the user connect from different device

Comment: I say user can't connect from 2 devices cause httpOnly is only readonly for the app and no one can access it from outside. so no one can access that and it is secure .

if a user connected from 2 devices 1 of them will disconnected when the expire_date comes

Comment: yes thank you, i also founded an other solution using web socket so i can logout the old user automatically thank you

Comment: @frouja Good luck , i will be happy if you send what you have found:)